# How to use Unicode in aspell dictionary?

Tags: linux, aspell

I'm trying to use `aspell` to check spelling in my text. I have a custom dictionary with exceptions. They are all in ASCII, but one word is in Unicode (`foo.en.pws`):

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 554
Foo
bar
Bárbara
```

Then, I run:

```
cat x.txt | aspell -a --encoding=utf-8 -p ./foo.en.pws
```

And I'm getting:

```
Error: ./foo.en.pws: The word "Bárbara" is invalid. 
The character '�' (U+A1) may not appear in the middle of a word.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a way, thanks to this documentation [page](http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html). The first line of the dictionary has to have `utf-8` at the end:

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 554 utf-8
Foo
bar
Bárbara
```